# How to add a jquery parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have this javascript to display my divs with jquery isotope

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
var $container = $('#box-content');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*', 
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false,
    }
});
</script>
```

And I need to add this parameter, but I don't know how, because I don't know javascript.

```
sortBy : 'random'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#box-content');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*', 
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        },
        sortBy: 'random'
    });
    </script>
```